# Rationalize the denominator of the fraction $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}$

Tags: geometry

Rationalize the denominator of the fraction $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}$$
My idea is to multiply the numerator and the denominator by ${\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}}.$ I got that $$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}}{a-b}$$
The answer in my book is $$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}}{a+b}$$ When $a=b=1$ my answer isn't defined, but their is equal to $1$ as it should be. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct, but it seems to me that the book is incorrect. Side note: your question is not about geometry.

Comment: Probably a typo in the book, change the + in the midle with -

Comment: Note that for the fraction we get after multiplication, the condition $a≠b$ holds.

Comment: When a=b=1, their answer is equal to 1 as it should ***not*** be (unless you made a mistake while typing the problem statement here).